# Best Practice to fetch nearby locations for Geofencing

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

So I am developing an app which notifies user when he enters a region (lets say 1 km radius) where an event is taking place. There can be many such events nearby him. I also have an API that will give me a list of the location for these events nearby his location. But the question is how to maintain a list of these nearby locations and mark them for geo-fencing. I can think of 3 ways to do so:

1) Periodic Task of 30min interval. So I can get a list of nearby events(10km radius) every 30min and mark them for geo-fencing. I can also check if after 30min he moved a minimum distance or not. If yes only then i'll fetch the fresh list from the API.

2) Mark his current location for Geo-fence with a radius of 10 km. and get a list of events in 10 km radius when he exits this region. After I get the list I'll mark them for Geo-fence and his current location also. (I don't know how feasible this is but seems like a perfect solution if it works).

3) Instead of fetching a list of events in 10km radius. I can fetch all the events in the city he has selected and mark them all for geo-fencing. Refresh this list in periodic Task once per day.

So which method is a better practice?